# variable contains $, expansion needed

Tags: shell, variable, su

The script fetches the path of a file via some command and then the mount command runs.

```
pkgname= #defined here

su -c "apkfile= #defined here &&\
stockapp=$(pm path $pkgname | sed -n '/base/s/package://p') &&\
mount -o bind $apkfile \$stockapp"
```

The apkfile path do not contains any special characters but the stock app path contains characters which fails the mount command cause they are expanded instead of treated literally.
I want to expand the variable and then put in single quotes

so the command becomes

```
mount -o /data/adb/path/apkname.apk '/data/app/~~$JwIEhjduwUE==com.google.android.youtube/base.apk'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to put the expanded variable and command substitution into single quotes:

```
apkfile= #defined here
pkgname= #defined here
su -c 'mount -o bind '\'"$apkfile"\'' '\'$(pm path "$pkgname" | sed -n '/base/s/package://p')\'
```